# Status bar with time-consuming operation not working in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I encountered a problem while trying to output the current program status to the status bar.

Here is my code:

```
void onBtnOpenPressed()
{
    ui.statusBar->showMessage("Running,please wait...");

    // some time-consuming operation with ui

    ui.statusBar->showMessage("Ready");
}
```

However, the status bar only displays "Ready"

Comment: Maybe the time-consuming operation doesn't consume enough time? And the `ui.statusBar` immediately overwrites previous msg. In any case, your `onBtnOpenPressed` looks like a slot, and slots should not block the main thread for too long to avoid GUI freezing.

Comment: The 'traditional' way do do this would be to run the time consuming operation on a separate thread and use the signal/slot mechanism (queued connection) to post updates to the GUI as/when required.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `qApp->processEvents();` right after `ui.statusBar->showMessage("Running,please wait...");` it should work as you want.

Comment: or `QApplication::processEvents();`

Comment: IMHO it's a hack, not a solution. Even in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) they discourage the use of this method. But without the details about OPs problem hard to tell anything more ofc. Normally "long operation", preferably not GUI related, should be done asynchronously and send the signal when it's finished.